Runtime Upgrade from standard Node Template to Frontier Template Node
I’m curious, is it possible to do a runtime upgrade that also adds EVM functionality?
Currently my project has a solochain that is already public and we’d like to integrate EVM functionality/compatibility through the means of a runtime upgrade.
Luckily, most of our runtime and node client have literally all of the necessary imports already but we just neglected to finish unifying the accounts and passing the fc and fp crates to everything.
I’m also open to the fact that we may need to do a new release for our client itself, but in that case is there a way to keep our current network while doing so?
Any answers, theories or suggestions are welcome!
